# What is the point of sanctions against Russia?

Tags: russian-federation, ukraine, sanctions

I'm trying to understand what is the point of the penalties against Russia as a result of the war. For example, consider the collapse of Russian currency (as a result of sanctions), wouldn't this effect the average Russian person more than the bureaucrats who passed the decisions?

Suppose Russia was a democracy, I could understand the idea of the sanctions as when the next elections come, people would choose a better leader who would not take such decisions which led to the sanctions. **However given the current political system, is there anything which is being achieved?**

Comment: Excuse me if this gets said as a bad faith post. I can't think of any 'better' way to frame this...

Comment: There might already be one or two questions here about it. Yes, they seem to have a very strong effect. Ordinary Russians who do not support Putin are a collateral in all of this. But then ordinary Ukrainians who just wanted to live in peace are a collateral too and pay even more dearly. If there was a way to target Putin and the people supporting him  and only those, it would probably be done.

Comment: "wouldn't this effect the average Russian person more than the bureaucrats who passed the decisions?" Yes. But *that would apply to anything else as well, including going to actual war with Russia*. This is an unavoidable and unpleasant reality of having to deal with a "political system" whose leader doesn't care how many of his own people suffer and die as long as he gets what he wants, and the problem is that they'll still suffer and die even if you give him what he wants.